# Laravel 5.1 Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel

> I have problem with my laravel 5.1 error Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany could not be converted to string when i click delete

**GalleryController.php**

```
public function deleteGallery($id)
{
    //load the gallery
    $currentGallery = Gallery::findOrfail($id);

    // check ownership
    if ($currentGallery->created_by != Auth::user()->id) {
        abort('403','You are not allowed to delete this gallery');
    }

    // get the images   
    $images = $currentGallery->images();    

    // delete the images
    foreach ($currentGallery->$images as $image) {
        unlink(public_path($image->file_path));
    }

    // delete the DB records
    $currentGallery->images()->delete();

    $currentGallery->delete();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**Route.php**

```
Route::get('gallery/delete/{id}','GalleryController@deleteGallery');
```

**Model Gallery.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Gallery extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'gallery';

    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
    }
}
```

**Model Image.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class image extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['gallery_id', 'file_name', 'file_size', 'file_mime', 'file_path', 
    'created_by'];

    public function gallery()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Gallery');
    }

}
```

**Views gallery.blade.php**

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h1>My Gallery</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @if ($galleries->count() > 0)
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr class="info">
                    <th>Name of the gallery</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>                
            <tbody> 
                @foreach($galleries as $gallery)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$gallery->name}}
                        <span class="pull-right">
                            {{ $gallery->images()->count() }}
                        </span>
                    </td>
                    <td><a href="{{url('gallery/view/'.$gallery->id)}}">View</a> / 
                        <a href="{{url('gallery/delete/'.$gallery->id)}}">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>       
                @endforeach             
            </tbody>
        </table>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
     @if (count($errors) > 0)
     <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
     </div>
     @endif
        <form class="form" method="POST" action="{{url('gallery/save')}}">  
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">  

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="gallery_name"
            id="gallery_name" placeholder="Name of the gallery" 
            class="form-control"
            value="{{ old('gallery_name')}}" />
        </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 4):

In the gallery controller you don't need to get the images since you’re not using the variable anywhere else. Hence remove the lines

```
// get the images   
$images = $currentGallery->images();
```

Just have the foreach be as

```
// delete the images
foreach ($currentGallery->images as $image) {
    unlink(public_path($image->file_path));
}
```

please note use of `$currentGallery->images`

Comment: thanks for your help Joseph :)  but i want ask something why only record in database can delete , file in my folder images cannot delete

Comment: can't see any functionality to delete from your folder images? Or is that the function of unlink??

Comment: that the function of unlink to delete file in folder image but not running well why ?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`$images = $currentGallery->images();`

To:

`$images = $currentGallery->images;`